# Retorno do webService em XML - php

Tags: php, web-service

Estou tentando consumir um webservice da TOTVs.

Meu código PHP:

```
// SOAP client


  $wsdl = 'http://localhost/TOTVSBusinessConnect/wsDataServer.asmx?wsdl';
  $endpoint = array
  (
    'location' => 'http://localhost/TOTVSBusinessConnect/wsDataServer.asmx'
  );
  $soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, $endpoint);
  $result = $soapClient->ReadRecordAuth(array('DataServerName' => 'GlbUsuarioData', 'PrimaryKey' => '$us', 'Contexto' => 'COLIGADA=1', 'Usuario' => $us, 'Senha' => $ps));
```

De retorno to fazendo assim:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result->ReadRecordAuthResult) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
var_dump($xml);
```

Mas recebo o seguinte resultado:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (0) {
}
```

Testei no SoapUI e me dá o seguinte resultado:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"> <soap:Header>
      <wsa:Action>http://www.totvs.com.br/br/ReadRecordAuthResponse</wsa:Action>

      <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
      <wsse:Security>
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-4c70a96c-e82b-4740-a617-17400c63dcd8">
            <wsu:Created>2016-12-28T11:11:52Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2016-12-28T11:16:52Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
      </wsse:Security>    </soap:Header>    <soap:Body>
      <ReadRecordAuthResponse xmlns="http://www.totvs.com.br/br/">
         <ReadRecordAuthResult><![CDATA[<GlbUsuario>   <xs:schema id="GlbUsuario" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="GlbUsuario" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true" msdata:EnforceConstraints="False">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="GUSUARIO">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="CODUSUARIO" msdata:Caption="Usuário" default="">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="20" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="NOME" msdata:Caption="Nome" minOccurs="0">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="45" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="STATUS" msdata:Caption="Ativo" type="xs:short" default="1" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="DATAINICIO" msdata:Caption="Início de Validade" msdata:DateTimeMode="Unspecified" type="xs:dateTime" default="2016-12-28T00:00:00" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="DATAEXPIRACAO" msdata:Caption="Expiração de Validade" msdata:DateTimeMode="Unspecified" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="CONFIRMABTNOK" msdata:Caption="Confirmação de Operação" type="xs:short" default="1" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="SENHA" msdata:Caption="Senha " type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="CONTROLE" msdata:Caption="CRC do Usuário" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="ULTIMACOLIGADA" msdata:Caption="Última Coligada Acessada" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="CODACESSO" msdata:Caption="Código de Acesso">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="16" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="DTAEXPSENHA" msdata:Caption="Data de expiração da senha" msdata:DateTimeMode="Unspecified" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="DIASEXPSENHA" msdata:Caption="Dias de expiração da senha" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="OBRIGAALTERARSENHA" msdata:Caption="Alterar senha no Próximo Login" default="T" minOccurs="0">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="1" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="NUMLOGININVALIDO" msdata:Caption="Número de Logins Inválidos" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="DATALOGININVALIDO" msdata:Caption="Data do último login inválido" msdata:DateTimeMode="Unspecified" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="EMAIL" msdata:Caption="E-Mail" minOccurs="0">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="60" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="ACESSONET" msdata:Caption="Permite Acesso ao TOTVS RM Portal" default="F" minOccurs="0">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="1" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="DATAULTIMOACESSO" msdata:Caption="Data de último acesso" msdata:DateTimeMode="Unspecified" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="CODUSUARIOREDE" msdata:Caption="Usuário de rede" minOccurs="0">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="20" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="DOMINIOREDE" msdata:Caption="Domínio de rede" minOccurs="0">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="256" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="LIVEID" msdata:ReadOnly="true" msdata:Caption="Usuário do Microsoft Live" minOccurs="0">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="150" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="USUARIOTWITTER" msdata:Caption="Usuário do Twitter" minOccurs="0">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="50" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="SENHATWITTER" msdata:Caption="Senha do Twitter" minOccurs="0">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="100" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="USUARIOFACEBOOK" minOccurs="0">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="50" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="SENHAFACEBOOK" minOccurs="0">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="100" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="USUARIOLINKEDIN" minOccurs="0">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="50" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="SENHALINKEDIN" minOccurs="0">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="100" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="FULLDETERMINED" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="USERID" msdata:Caption="UserId" default="" minOccurs="0">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="50" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="INTERNO1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="DATAULTIMOACESSOVALIDO" msdata:DateTimeMode="Unspecified" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="GPERMIS">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="CODCOLIGADA" type="xs:short" />
                <xs:element name="CODSISTEMA" default="G">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="1" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="CODUSUARIO" default="brunno.nascimento">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="20" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="SUPERVISOR" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="CONTROLE" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="CRIARELAT" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="RECCREATEDBY" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="RECCREATEDON" msdata:DateTimeMode="Unspecified" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="RECMODIFIEDBY" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="RECMODIFIEDON" msdata:DateTimeMode="Unspecified" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="GUSRPERFIL">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="CODCOLIGADA" type="xs:short" />
                <xs:element name="CODUSUARIO" default="brunno.nascimento">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="20" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="CODSISTEMA" default="G">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="1" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="CODPERFIL">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="15" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="INDICE" type="xs:short" />
                <xs:element name="CONTROLE" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="RECCREATEDBY" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="RECCREATEDON" msdata:DateTimeMode="Unspecified" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="RECMODIFIEDBY" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="RECMODIFIEDON" msdata:DateTimeMode="Unspecified" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="STATUS" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:unique name="Constraint1" msdata:PrimaryKey="true">
        <xs:selector xpath=".//GUSUARIO" />
        <xs:field xpath="CODUSUARIO" />
      </xs:unique>
      <xs:unique name="GPERMIS_Constraint1" msdata:ConstraintName="Constraint1" msdata:PrimaryKey="true">
        <xs:selector xpath=".//GPERMIS" />
        <xs:field xpath="CODCOLIGADA" />
        <xs:field xpath="CODSISTEMA" />
        <xs:field xpath="CODUSUARIO" />
      </xs:unique>
      <xs:unique name="GUSRPERFIL_Constraint1" msdata:ConstraintName="Constraint1" msdata:PrimaryKey="true">
        <xs:selector xpath=".//GUSRPERFIL" />
        <xs:field xpath="CODCOLIGADA" />
        <xs:field xpath="CODUSUARIO" />
        <xs:field xpath="CODSISTEMA" />
        <xs:field xpath="CODPERFIL" />
      </xs:unique>
      <xs:keyref name="FK_GUSUARIO_GPERMIS" refer="Constraint1">
        <xs:selector xpath=".//GPERMIS" />
        <xs:field xpath="CODUSUARIO" />
      </xs:keyref>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <msdata:Relationship name="FKGUSRPERFIL_GPERMIS" msdata:parent="GPERMIS" msdata:child="GUSRPERFIL" msdata:parentkey="CODCOLIGADA CODSISTEMA CODUSUARIO" msdata:childkey="CODCOLIGADA CODSISTEMA CODUSUARIO" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>   </xs:schema>   <GUSUARIO>
    <CODUSUARIO>usuario</CODUSUARIO>
    <NOME>nomeusuario</NOME>
    <STATUS>1</STATUS>
    <DATAINICIO>2015-10-01T00:00:00</DATAINICIO>
    <CONFIRMABTNOK>1</CONFIRMABTNOK>    
    <CONTROLE>31921</CONTROLE>
    <ULTIMACOLIGADA>1</ULTIMACOLIGADA>
    <CODACESSO>Default</CODACESSO>
    <DTAEXPSENHA>2015-12-08T00:00:00</DTAEXPSENHA>
    <OBRIGAALTERARSENHA>F</OBRIGAALTERARSENHA>
    <NUMLOGININVALIDO>0</NUMLOGININVALIDO>
    <EMAIL>emailusuario</EMAIL>
    <ACESSONET>F</ACESSONET>
    <DATAULTIMOACESSO>2016-12-28T09:11:52.28</DATAULTIMOACESSO>
    <SENHATWITTER>\FEz\1B\7F1\18\B7\27</SENHATWITTER>
    <SENHAFACEBOOK>\FEz\1B\7F1\18\B7\27</SENHAFACEBOOK>
    <SENHALINKEDIN>\FEz\1B\7F1\18\B7\27</SENHALINKEDIN>
    <FULLDETERMINED />
    <USERID>01a8d451-7105-4d79-8761-e2c39ecc7ca4</USERID>
    <DATAULTIMOACESSOVALIDO>2016-12-28T09:11:52.28</DATAULTIMOACESSOVALIDO> </GUSUARIO> </GlbUsuario>]]></ReadRecordAuthResult>
      </ReadRecordAuthResponse>    </soap:Body> </soap:Envelope>
```

Na aba "Raw" me apresenta:

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Length: 16422
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=tfy4ersu0eyplf12osjb133n; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 28 Dec 2016 11:11:52 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><soap:Header><wsa:Action>http://www.totvs.com.br/br/ReadRecordAuthResponse</wsa:Action><wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:f6e378f5-24b2-42eb-9b10-87d6269bc7ab</wsa:MessageID><wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:480adf3b-5fd0-4319-952f-b88d8718ffd5</wsa:RelatesTo><wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To><wsse:Security><wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-4c70a96c-e82b-4740-a617-17400c63dcd8"><wsu:Created>2016-12-28T11:11:52Z</wsu:Created><wsu:Expires>2016-12-28T11:16:52Z</wsu:Expires></wsu:Timestamp></wsse:Security></soap:Header><soap:Body><ReadRecordAuthResponse xmlns="http://www.totvs.com.br/br/"><ReadRecordAuthResult>&lt;GlbUsuario&gt;
  &lt;xs:schema id="GlbUsuario" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"&gt;
    &lt;xs:element name="GlbUsuario" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true" msdata:EnforceConstraints="False"&gt;
      &lt;xs:complexType&gt;
        &lt;xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"&gt;
          &lt;xs:element name="GUSUARIO"&gt;
            &lt;xs:complexType&gt;
              &lt;xs:sequence&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="CODUSUARIO" msdata:Caption="UsuÃ¡rio" default=""&gt;
                  &lt;xs:simpleType&gt;
                    &lt;xs:restriction base="xs:string"&gt;
                      &lt;xs:maxLength value="20" /&gt;
                    &lt;/xs:restriction&gt;
                  &lt;/xs:simpleType&gt;
                &lt;/xs:element&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="NOME" msdata:Caption="Nome" minOccurs="0"&gt;
                  &lt;xs:simpleType&gt;
                    &lt;xs:restriction base="xs:string"&gt;
                      &lt;xs:maxLength value="45" /&gt;
                    &lt;/xs:restriction&gt;
                  &lt;/xs:simpleType&gt;
                &lt;/xs:element&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="STATUS" msdata:Caption="Ativo" type="xs:short" default="1" minOccurs="0" /&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="DATAINICIO" msdata:Caption="InÃ­cio de Validade" msdata:DateTimeMode="Unspecified" type="xs:dateTime" default="2016-12-28T00:00:00" minOccurs="0" /&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="DATAEXPIRACAO" msdata:Caption="ExpiraÃ§Ã£o de Validade" msdata:DateTimeMode="Unspecified" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" /&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="CONFIRMABTNOK" msdata:Caption="ConfirmaÃ§Ã£o de OperaÃ§Ã£o" type="xs:short" default="1" minOccurs="0" /&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="SENHA" msdata:Caption="Senha " type="xs:string" /&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="CONTROLE" msdata:Caption="CRC do UsuÃ¡rio" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" /&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="ULTIMACOLIGADA" msdata:Caption="Ãšltima Coligada Acessada" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" /&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="CODACESSO" msdata:Caption="CÃ³digo de Acesso"&gt;
                  &lt;xs:simpleType&gt;
                    &lt;xs:restriction base="xs:string"&gt;
                      &lt;xs:maxLength value="16" /&gt;
                    &lt;/xs:restriction&gt;
                  &lt;/xs:simpleType&gt;
                &lt;/xs:element&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="DTAEXPSENHA" msdata:Caption="Data de expiraÃ§Ã£o da senha" msdata:DateTimeMode="Unspecified" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" /&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="DIASEXPSENHA" msdata:Caption="Dias de expiraÃ§Ã£o da senha" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" /&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="OBRIGAALTERARSENHA" msdata:Caption="Alterar senha no PrÃ³ximo Login" default="T" minOccurs="0"&gt;
                  &lt;xs:simpleType&gt;
                    &lt;xs:restriction base="xs:string"&gt;
                      &lt;xs:maxLength value="1" /&gt;
                    &lt;/xs:restriction&gt;
                  &lt;/xs:simpleType&gt;
                &lt;/xs:element&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="NUMLOGININVALIDO" msdata:Caption="NÃºmero de Logins InvÃ¡lidos" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" /&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="DATALOGININVALIDO" msdata:Caption="Data do Ãºltimo login invÃ¡lido" msdata:DateTimeMode="Unspecified" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" /&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="EMAIL" msdata:Caption="E-Mail" minOccurs="0"&gt;
                  &lt;xs:simpleType&gt;
                    &lt;xs:restriction base="xs:string"&gt;
                      &lt;xs:maxLength value="60" /&gt;
                    &lt;/xs:restriction&gt;
                  &lt;/xs:simpleType&gt;
                &lt;/xs:element&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="ACESSONET" msdata:Caption="Permite Acesso ao TOTVS RM Portal" default="F" minOccurs="0"&gt;
                  &lt;xs:simpleType&gt;
                    &lt;xs:restriction base="xs:string"&gt;
                      &lt;xs:maxLength value="1" /&gt;
                    &lt;/xs:restriction&gt;
                  &lt;/xs:simpleType&gt;
                &lt;/xs:element&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="DATAULTIMOACESSO" msdata:Caption="Data de Ãºltimo acesso" msdata:DateTimeMode="Unspecified" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" /&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="CODUSUARIOREDE" msdata:Caption="UsuÃ¡rio de rede" minOccurs="0"&gt;
                  &lt;xs:simpleType&gt;
                    &lt;xs:restriction base="xs:string"&gt;
                      &lt;xs:maxLength value="20" /&gt;
                    &lt;/xs:restriction&gt;
                  &lt;/xs:simpleType&gt;
                &lt;/xs:element&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="DOMINIOREDE" msdata:Caption="DomÃ­nio de rede" minOccurs="0"&gt;
                  &lt;xs:simpleType&gt;
                    &lt;xs:restriction base="xs:string"&gt;
                      &lt;xs:maxLength value="256" /&gt;
                    &lt;/xs:restriction&gt;
                  &lt;/xs:simpleType&gt;
                &lt;/xs:element&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="LIVEID" msdata:ReadOnly="true" msdata:Caption="UsuÃ¡rio do Microsoft Live" minOccurs="0"&gt;
                  &lt;xs:simpleType&gt;
                    &lt;xs:restriction base="xs:string"&gt;
                      &lt;xs:maxLength value="150" /&gt;
                    &lt;/xs:restriction&gt;
                  &lt;/xs:simpleType&gt;
                &lt;/xs:element&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="USUARIOTWITTER" msdata:Caption="UsuÃ¡rio do Twitter" minOccurs="0"&gt;
                  &lt;xs:simpleType&gt;
                    &lt;xs:restriction base="xs:string"&gt;
                      &lt;xs:maxLength value="50" /&gt;
                    &lt;/xs:restriction&gt;
                  &lt;/xs:simpleType&gt;
                &lt;/xs:element&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="SENHATWITTER" msdata:Caption="Senha do Twitter" minOccurs="0"&gt;
                  &lt;xs:simpleType&gt;
                    &lt;xs:restriction base="xs:string"&gt;
                      &lt;xs:maxLength value="100" /&gt;
                    &lt;/xs:restriction&gt;
                  &lt;/xs:simpleType&gt;
                &lt;/xs:element&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="USUARIOFACEBOOK" minOccurs="0"&gt;
                  &lt;xs:simpleType&gt;
                    &lt;xs:restriction base="xs:string"&gt;
                      &lt;xs:maxLength value="50" /&gt;
                    &lt;/xs:restriction&gt;
                  &lt;/xs:simpleType&gt;
                &lt;/xs:element&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="SENHAFACEBOOK" minOccurs="0"&gt;
                  &lt;xs:simpleType&gt;
                    &lt;xs:restriction base="xs:string"&gt;
                      &lt;xs:maxLength value="100" /&gt;
                    &lt;/xs:restriction&gt;
                  &lt;/xs:simpleType&gt;
                &lt;/xs:element&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="USUARIOLINKEDIN" minOccurs="0"&gt;
                  &lt;xs:simpleType&gt;
                    &lt;xs:restriction base="xs:string"&gt;
                      &lt;xs:maxLength value="50" /&gt;
                    &lt;/xs:restriction&gt;
                  &lt;/xs:simpleType&gt;
                &lt;/xs:element&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="SENHALINKEDIN" minOccurs="0"&gt;
                  &lt;xs:simpleType&gt;
                    &lt;xs:restriction base="xs:string"&gt;
                      &lt;xs:maxLength value="100" /&gt;
                    &lt;/xs:restriction&gt;
                  &lt;/xs:simpleType&gt;
                &lt;/xs:element&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="FULLDETERMINED" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="USERID" msdata:Caption="UserId" default="" minOccurs="0"&gt;
                  &lt;xs:simpleType&gt;
                    &lt;xs:restriction base="xs:string"&gt;
                      &lt;xs:maxLength value="50" /&gt;
                    &lt;/xs:restriction&gt;
                  &lt;/xs:simpleType&gt;
                &lt;/xs:element&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="INTERNO1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /&gt;
                &lt;xs:element name="DATAULTIMOACESSOVALIDO" msdata:DateTimeMode="Uns
```

Se puderem me ajudar, agradeço !

Answer (score -1):

Tente desse jeito

```
try{
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => $trace, 'exceptions' => $exceptions));
    $response = $client->ReadRecordAuth(array('DataServerName' => 'GlbUsuarioData', 'PrimaryKey' => '$us', 'Contexto' => 'COLIGADA=1', 'Usuario' => $us, 'Senha' => $ps));
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
     echo "Error!";
     echo $e -> getMessage ();
     echo 'Last response: '. $client->__getLastResponse();
 }
 echo "<pre>";
    print_r($response);
 echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Tentei Lucas, duas coisas:
O que seria as variáveis $trace e $exceptions ?
Me retornou assim:

stdClass Object
(
    [ReadRecordAuthResult] => 
"um espaço gigante"
)

Comment: No SOAPUI tem uma aba "Raw" no lugar onde vc envia sua requisição, pode mostrar o que está lá ? @BrunnoSena

Comment: Sobre sua duvida @BrunnoSena http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/soapclient.soapclient.php

Comment: Lucas, editei o post colocando o aparece no "Raw"

Comment: @BrunnoSena no retorno, ao invés de especificar a simplexml_load_string($result->ReadRecordAuthResult) . O que acontece quando vc retorno o conteúdo inteiro?

Comment: Me retorna isso:
Warning: simplexml_load_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\exemplos\webservice\index.php on line 112 Error: Cannot create object

Comment: Sim, isso é porque é necessário ao menos um parâmetro. Ok! E quando vc gera o arquivo xml de retorno, você consegue ler ele com simplexml_load_file($arquivo)?

Comment: Não sei como fazer esse código pra gerar o xml.

Comment: Do mesmo jeito que gera um arquivo txt qualquer